# VPN Error 937: hay otra conexión de este tipo en uso. No es posible mas de un acceso en simultaneo?

Tags: vpn

Para una empresa, a la cual algunos de sus empleados necesitan acceder a su sistema de gestión remotamente, se implementó una VPN en la Pc principal ("servidor") donde se encuentra la base de datos a la que necesita acceder el sistema. La VPN funciona correctamente y el sistema puede acceder sin problemas, el único inconveniente es que no permite mas de una conexión a la vez en la VPN. La misma esta montada sobre un Windows 7 Pro. Por lo que se estuvo investigando, para permitir mas de una conexión a la vez la VPN debe estar en un Windows Server, es asi? Que otra alternativa se puede utilizar para comunicar varias pc clientes con ese "servidor"?

Comment: Es un foro de programacion.

Comment: Que servicio usas para el VPN? OpenVPN, PPTP? como lo montaste y con que?

Comment: me sucedió los mismo y resolvi adquiriendo un router que administrara VPN y listo. para lo que realmente necesitas hacer, requieres usar un SO, dedicado a SERVERs